# SSIS Package Configuration option resets when collapsing / expanding options tree

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, ssis

*On Visual Studio 2013 with SSDT for SQL Server 2014*

I noticed something very strange.

I am viewing the package configuration selected option for a package:

[image: Package configuration before collapsing / expanding]

Now, i just click on the - sign and then on the plus sign on the "Properties" branch. And the option is cleared:

[image]

The ONLY way i found not to mess everything is just to have ALL the options FULL expanded and THEN to select what i want.

Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 0):

Finally added this as a bug to MS Connect site and seems like MS thinks its a bug by their response...

[LINK TO BUG REPORT](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1008125/ssis-package-configuration-option-resets-when-collapsing-expanding-options-tree)